# Twitter4j throws 'No authentication challenges found' after canceling login

Tags: android, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J for posting some tweets. 
When I try to post a tweet I open a webview with the authenticationURL to log in:

```
twitterRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK);

Intent i = new Intent(FutbolTvActivity.this, TwitterWebLoginActivity.class);
i.putExtra("URL", twitterRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

If I complete the process I get logged OK and can send the tweet. 
The problem is that if I click on cancel button on login web page and I try to login again I receive the next exception on

```
twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.TWITTER_CALLBACK): No authentication challenges found
```

If I reuse the previous authentication URL the webview shows an error message saying this URL is too old.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is because you might have not added **Callback URL** while creating your OAuth Keys..

Comment: Did you mean when I create the app on dev.twitter.com??

Comment: We changed Callback URL some time after creating the OAth keys. It could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:

At first time I was using:

```
twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton()
```

for getting the Twitter object. By this way the second time I call to getOAuthRequestToken() I get the error described above.

No, I'm using:

```
twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration.build()).getInstance();
```

so I have different instances every time I start the related activity. By this way, I never call a second time over the same instance to getOAuthRequestToken() so I have no errors.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound weird but try to set your time/date update automatically. Based on my previous experience this was the problem. When i set this and after the phone time is synced, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Callback URL is not the reason, it take sometime to reset the keys. Check that your keys are correct and time is sync.. There is an issue arise few days ago which is fixed now. Make sure that any of the fields asking for URLs ("Website" and "Callback URL") are fully qualified, non-twitter.com domains.
May be it's possible your application name is already in use by another application. Experiment with different names and attempt to save again.

Check this link [Temporary issue with creating applications](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/317)

Check on your emulator, may be your device time is not sync. It won't work if your time is not sync.

The library is also updated.. Check this link [Discussing API v1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/current-status-api-v1.1) and this too [Issue with twitter: Unable to retrieve the access token. Status: 401.](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=48)

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I think all configuration parameters and time are OK beacause I can get logged and post tweets without problems. I only get the error if I click on cancel button at getAuthenticationURL() webpage and try to getOAuthRequestToken() for a second time...